# When is an html element considered empty? How does this affect margins?

Tags: html

I have used google chrome (webkit) in determining behavior:

`<p>Test <span style="margin-left:20px"> </span>test</p>`

doesn't add margin-left, but:

`<p>Test<span style="margin-left:20px"> </span>test</p>`

does.

Why? Is margin-left not applied to empty elements? Why is it considered empty in one case and not the other?

(This is important for a program stripping extra whitespace)

Comment: Both works anyways http://jsfiddle.net/L9uRG/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because browsers by default merge two and more consecutive white characters (and space is one of them). So in the first example the space within `<span>` is not visible at all and that's why `margin` is not applied.

You can proof that using `<pre>` tag, which stops white character merging. Check the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wAx2w/).

Comment: Aha. Are margins never applied to invisible content? Is this (not showing margins...) a chrome thing, or is it part of the html/css specs?

Comment: You have to check on other browsers, but I would guess it's how html works because of specification.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `<p>....</p>` in between `<pre></pre>`.
This will shows you exactly what you needed.